# Initialization of query failed - BW_REPORTING_FPM001 error

Tags: sap-fiori, sap-bw, s4hana

I am implementing Trial Balance(Version 2) FPM/WebDynpro App from [Fiori Apps Library](https://fioriappslibrary.hana.ondemand.com/sap/fix/externalViewer/#/detail/Apps%28%27F0996%27%29/S6OP)

following App Implementation : Trial Balance guide for S/4 Hana 1610.

When I launch the Trial Balance App. It says

> Search: Null object exception
>
> Initialization of query 2CCFITRIALBALQ0001 Failed
>
> BW_REPORTING_FPM001
>
> [image: Screenshot]

Please let me know how to Initialize or Activate BEx Query.

Regards,

Sayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is resolved following the below steps :

1) Set a BW-client: Transaction SE37 RS_MANDT_UNIQUE_SET. If you use only one client, then fill I_MANDT with this one. If you use multiple clients, choose one of these.

2) Set user parameters  RSWAD_DEV_MDVERSION = ‘072’ and RSWAD_SKIP_JAVA = ‘X’ for user DDIC(Its setting in transaction SU01 under parameter tab)

3) Logon to system with user DDIC in the client you used in step 1 and perform transaction RSTCO_ADMIN in order to activate the technical objects, which are needed for the engine. The parameters set in step 2 avoid, that unnecessary objects (related to BI tools based on JAVA) are activated here.

4) If you don't look at the OLAP-statistics you should deactivate these: Transaction SE38 - execute Report SAP_RSADMIN_MAINTAIN: with OBJECT = RSDDSTAT_GLOBAL_OFF and VALUE = X in insert mode. If you need the statistics, you can switch these on by running the program with that object but VALUE = space in update mode.

5) If you want to use OData-Services run report EQ_RS_AUTO_SETUP (transaction SE38)

6) If you want to use the BW time hierarchies, go to transaction RSRHIERARCHYVIRT and mark the hierarchies you need - for this you have to wait until the job triggered in step 3 has finished successfully
7) Call function module RSEC_GENERATE_BI_ALL.

Regards,

Rehan Sayed